# Seeing Blank page After refresh in nested routes in React Router

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Here is my main router page in `App.js`:

```
<Provider store={store}>
    <Router>
        <Switch>
            <Route exact path = "/" component= {FormPage}></Route>
            <Route  path = "/dashboard" component= {Dashboard}></Route>
        </Switch>
    </Router>
</Provider>
```

And in Dashboard Page:

```
<Router>
    <Switch>
        <Route  path = "/register" component= {Registration}></Route>
        <Route  path = "/home" component= {Home}></Route>
    </Switch>
</Router>
```

After refresh in register or home page, nothing renders. But the route in `App.js` file working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   <Router>
       <Switch>
          <Route  path = "/dashboard/register" component= {Registration}> 
          </Route>
          <Route  path = "/dashboard/home" component= {Home}></Route>
      </Switch>
    </Router>
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn of it - what have you changed, and why?

Answer (score 0):

This is because react is not able to locate the history of the url which is been naviagted by users.
Basically react property will search for the url which is saved in history but here developer didn't use that.

```
const history = useHistory();
        <Router  history= {history}>
            <Switch>
                <Route  path = "/register" component= {Registration}></Route>
                <Route  path = "/home" component= {Home}></Route>
            </Switch>
        </Router>
```

To solve that follow these three steps and also refer above code.

1. import history like this **import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";**
2. assign to a variable like this **const history = useHistory();** and
3. use that in the main div/router which all the component is wrapped inside it